# Apex callout to a SSL endpoint: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: apex, callout, certificates, ssl

since some days I get the following error message when I call an webservice from SF:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have read different other comments etc. here but I still do not have a clue why this happens. When I check the remote site with:

https://www.digicert.com/help/

and enter my subdomain: **subdomain.example.com** everything besides the following is **green**:

```
The server is not sending the required intermediate certificate.
```

But I do not think that this is the point or?

What I know:

- Simple GET request with Basic Auth
- Postman call works

  - When I go to global settings and turn off 'SSL Verification'
- Curl call works
- SF do not work round about from the 28th of January. Was working all the time before.
- There is/was a Self-signed certificate in SF that expires on the 28th

  - This certificate is/was def. not used in Apex code
- I'm not sure if this self signed certificate was even used for this service or was just there (because SF creates one)
- The webservice is running on a Tomcat
- The certificate chain from the endpoint is valid (see pic)
- Admin of the tomcat server told me that he couln't find the 'old/expired' certificate anywhere.

So what would be the next steps here?

- Create a new self-signed certificate and add it to the webservice in tomcat?
- How this can be checked besides SF callouts?

I'm happy about any ideas/recommendations.

[image: Cert chain]

Comment: As already mentioned: https://www.digicert.com/help/ did not help me because everything looks good. And SSL Server Test is similar just a more comprehensive overview of the results. 
And the last one with the trusted self signed certificates: I understand this but why this issue happens during the last days? Before everything was working fine

Comment: If [digicert.com/help](https://www.digicert.com/help/) complains about server not sending the right intermediate cert, then Salesforce would complain too. The verification of a cert chain is a standard procedure. You can try `openssl` for a good measure if you want definitive verification. Likely reason is that something changed with respect to SSL config on your web service